# Android: Passing data from Java file to an activity

Tags: java, android

I have a Java file that contains Java function that is called in an activity Java.
However I don't know how to pass some data from the Java function file to the activity Java so that I could display it in the app.

Some coding in the Java function file (FaceView.java)

```
public class FaceView extends View {

private FaceListener mFaceListener;

interface FaceListener {
     void handleData(int[] cxArr, int[] cyArr);    
}

public void setFaceListener(FaceListener faceListener) {
    this.mFaceListener = faceListener;
}

private int cx;
private int cy;
private int[] cxArr;
private int[] cyArr;

private void drawFaceAnnotations(Canvas canvas, double scale) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mFaces.size(); ++i) {
        Face face = mFaces.valueAt(i);

        for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
            cx = (int) (landmark.getPosition().x * scale);
            cy = (int) (landmark.getPosition().y * scale);
            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 5, paint);
            cxArr[i] = cx;
            cyArr[i] = cy;
            mFaceListener.handleData(cxArr,cyArr);
        }
}
    }
}
```

Code in Activity java file (DisplayActivity.java)

```
 overlay.setFaceListener(new FaceView.FaceListener() {
 public void handleData(int[] cxArr, int[] cyArr) {

 System.out.println(cxArr[1]+" "+cyArr[1]);
     }
  });
```

Anyone have any idea how to pass data from FaceView.java to DisplayActivity.java?
I tried intend/bundle but doesn't seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: The reason for the data passing is that I will create a text view to display the data on the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a callback from your view to your activity.

Add an interface to your View implementation and invoke it when you need:

```
public class FaceView extends View {

    private FaceListener mFaceListener;

    interface FaceListener {
        public void handleData(Integer[] cxArr, Integer[] cyArr);
    }

    public void setFaceListener(FaceListener faceListener) {
        this.mFaceListener = faceListener;
    }


    private void drawFaceAnnotations(Canvas canvas, double scale) {
        // your code here
        // notify listener

       List<Integer> cxList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       List<Integer> cyList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

       for (int i = 0; i < mFaces.size(); ++i) {
           Face face = mFaces.valueAt(i);

           for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
                cx = (int) (landmark.getPosition().x * scale);
                cy = (int) (landmark.getPosition().y * scale);
                canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 5, paint);

                cxList.add(cx);
                cyList.add(cy);

            }
        }

        Integer[] cxArr = cxList.toArray(new Integer[cxList.size()]);
        Integer[] cyArr = cyList.toArray(new Integer[cyList.size()]);

        mFaceListener.handleData(cxArr,cyArr);
    }
}
```

Set callback/interface at your activity:

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // your code here
        FaceView overlay = (FaceView) findViewById(R.id.faceView);
        overlay.setFaceListener(new FaceView.FaceListener(){
             public void handleData(int[] cxArr, int[] cyArr) {
                 // TODO: handle faces array here
             } 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thx. is it possible to pass an array of cx and cy using the listener since the data to be passed is in a for loop.

Comment: Sure. You are writing the callback, you can pass anything you want, just modify the interface method. (Edit FaceListener's handleData method, change its parameters.

Comment: Do I have to declare a new array of variable for the handleData method or change cx and cy into array type? Srry I'm new to this

Comment: ok, I've edited my answer. I've just changed the parameter of the callback method. You can use your mFaces array at your activity.

Comment: Thanks! But by passing only mFace in the parameter will the cx and cy be passed individually? I need them to be separated. One more thing... in TODO how do I display the nth coordinates? For example I want to display only the 3rd coordinate.

Comment: This is because I want to call individual cx and cy in activity java like display cx[1]  -> 2nd x coordinate

Comment: Just iterate over mFace's Landmarks at drawFaceAnnotations method, create arrays for cx and cy and put their values into that array. Then modify the handleData method at interface, change  (SparseArray<Face> faces) to (int[] cxArr, int[] cyArr). Or simply do not change this method signature and move your for loops into activity. BTW try to understand the code I've written.

Comment: I've tried my best to understand ur coding and tried them but it made my app crashed and came out error about  java.lang.NullPointerException. Could you please check my edited post and tells me what's wrong. Thanks

Comment: you haven't initialized the arrays(cxArr, cyArr) that's why your app is crashed. You should start using logcat to understand the crash details which shows the problem with its line. Also I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have a `getter` method in `FaceView` class. Since you have a reference to this class in the `DisplayActivity`, you could simply call this method to pass the data.

So from you comment, you need to pass `cx` and `cy`. I take it these are int coordinates. Since you can return only one value in java method and you have two, I am using `Point`. But you could use `Array` or `ArrayList`.  Do something like the following.

FaceView.java

```
 private int cx;
 private int cy;

 public Point getCoordinates(){
       return new Point(cx, cy);
 }
```

DisplayActivity.java

```
 final Point point = overlay.getCoordinates();
 int cx = point.x;
 int cy = point.y;
```

This is not technically `passing data from FaceView to DisplayActivity`, but `fetching data of FaceView from DispalyActivity`. You can use this method if this is sufficient for you. I suggest this from your comment `The reason for the data passing is that I will create a text view to display the data on the app`.

On the other hand, if you want to notify `DisplayActivity` immediately about a change in `FaceView` then you need to set a listener for it via creating an iterface (See DevrimTuncer's answer).

Comment: I still doesn't quite get it. What should I replace with in .getSomeData() to obtain cx and cy in DisplayActivity?